# Zendframework Routing Issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I have been setting my routes in my application.ini file which works for all the ones i have setup. The problem is when there are multiple actions within that controller and i try to use the routes in other actions.

For instance i have created the following in my application.ini for paging and column sorting

```
resources.router.routes.search.route = "search/:page/:col/:sort/:limit/"
resources.router.routes.search.defaults.controller = search
resources.router.routes.search.defaults.page = 1
resources.router.routes.search.defaults.col = time
resources.router.routes.search.defaults.sort = default
resources.router.routes.search.defaults.limit = 50
resources.router.routes.search.reqs.page = \d+
resources.router.routes.search.reqs.col = \w+
resources.router.routes.search.reqs.sort = \w+
resources.router.routes.search.reqs.limit = \d+
```

The above works when I'm on the default action of that page like

```
www.mywebsite.com/search/2/
```

Would bring up the second page of the results. But if I try the same on another action,

```
www.mywebsite.com/search/action/2
```

It just shows a blank page. I tried creating its own settings in the ini and that did not work. I've run across this problem before but usually just gave up and separated things into different controllers but i would rather have different actions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

`search/:page/:col/:sort/:limit/` doesn't match `www.mywebsite.com/search/action/2`. Your route is looking for `search/` followed by a digit (`\d`) that represents the page number; however, you're requesting `search/` followed by the string `action`. I would suggest adding another parameter to your route: `search/:action/:page/:col/:sort/:limit`, defaulting `action` to `index`.

Requesting the first page of the default action stays the same (`search`). Requesting page 2 of the default route will now be `search/index/2/`, but you can now specify a different action (`search/action/2`).

Comment: Thank you for you input, I have actually tried that already but ended up with the same results.  The funny thing is i do the search again, it will default to that second page, but when the url params are there the page will not load.  I'm almost at a point where i'm going to separate it to it's own controller.  The only other routing i have is similar but for a different controller.  Would there be a better way of implementing the paging across all controllers and actions?

Comment: Below is what i recently tried based off another post I found but it still doesn't work.  The weirdest thing, is that if i search on that page, then click on the paging, it comes up blank, but if i search again it defaults to page two because it can read the params in the browser, just wont page for some reason. I'll add my other portion of my application.ini below this comment since i'm running out of room in this comment

Comment: resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.route = "search/advanced/:page/:limit/"
resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.defaults.controller = search
resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.defaults.action = advanced
resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.defaults.page = 1
resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.defaults.limit = 25
resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.reqs.page = \d+
resources.router.routes.searchadvanced.reqs.limit = \d+

The post that gave me this idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850558/php-zend-route-config-ini-similar-patterns